# Android Maps v2 rotate mapView with compass

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm developing an app which needs to rotate the mapView with a compass. I know how to rotate the camera but I need to rotate the mapView with the compass. the center point should be the current location. I found codes for Maps V1 but I need to do it with Maps V2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

OK, i figured it out myself. first you need to calculate the bearing from the compass.
then the Maps api-2 camera can be rotated.

```
public void updateCamera(float bearing) {
            CameraPosition currentPlace = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(centerLatitude, centerLongitude))
                    .bearing(bearing).tilt(65.5f).zoom(18f).build();
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(currentPlace));

    }
```

set `SensorListener` in your code and call this method in `onSensorChanged` event. i have added a tilt value so the map will rotate in 3D.

Comment: Not that it matters too much, but .bearing is a float.

Comment: How do you get bearing?

Comment: If you are using GoogleMap instead of MapView, you can use the mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener event.

Comment: How can we do this in V3? Please suggest. 
Also, I have posted similar question in order to rotate map 360 Degree by changing bearing 3 times (each time by 120 Degree to rotate 1 cycle around a center point) but there are easing and jerks. How can I avoid that. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123738/gmap-bearing-rotation-in-smooth-motion

Comment: Sure would be nice if you would show how you got the bearing, pretty important piece if information.

Comment: You can get bearing value form the Location (Current location) return by the location provider.

Answer (score 3):

in your GoogleMap object you can access getMyLocation method. This last returns a Location object which contains getBearing method. This one returns a float [0..360] computed from last known location and current location, 0° is the north axis, rotation is in the clock sens.

To resume, you can use a code like:

```
GoogleMap gMap = ..... 
float bearing = gMap.getMyLocation().getBearing();
CameraPosition newCamPos = new CameraPosition(latLngObject,
            zoomValue,
            tiltValue,
            bearing);
gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newCamPos), durationValue, null);
```

Comment: How can we do this in V3? Please suggest. 
Also I have posted similar question in order to rotate map 360 Degree by changing bearing 3 times (each time by 120 Degree to rotate 1 cycle around a center point) but there are easing and jerks. How can I avoid that. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123738/gmap-bearing-rotation-in-smooth-motion