# android GoogleMap programmatically rotate

Tags: android, google-maps, rotation

I am working on an activity with a com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap that covers a city where the street grid does not line up exactly with N/S/E/W. I would like to have the map rotated a bit when the activity loads. The user can still change the orientation so this would just be on load.

Here are two image. One is what the current behavior is and one is desired behavior. I don't need an exact degree rotation - just a means of rotating.

Current:
[image]

Desired:
[image]

Comment: i think you are trying to get somthing like described at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767282/android-maps-v2-rotate-mapview-with-compass