# How to keep map orientation fixed towards North in android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-maps-v2

i want to keep my maps orientation always towards north .If the location changes towards left in driving mode ,It should always align it towards north.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two orientations

**1.North-up**

**2.Track-up**

i think these both are pretty explainable by their name itself.

About the one you are asking is **North-up**.

The exact implementation of North-up is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320015/android-maps-auto-rotate)

Comment: The one which i implement is that it gets rotated towards north only once at the start..but after map point moves left or right , it should move camera towards north at that time also which is not happening

Comment: The thing you are looking is camera position **bearing** in map. you can find the documentation [here] (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.Builder)  set the bearing as 0.

Comment: on every location change i want to change camera position